# How to fetch battery information in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, battery

In my project, I want to display battery information in details. With `UIDevice` I can get battery level easily, but my demand is much more that just that. I want to obtain such battery health ,cycle count, voltage and even more details about the battery. (the more the better!! ). I really need some advice, thanks!

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://github.com/Shmoopi/iOS-System-Services) ?

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava The battery information found there is the same that you get from UIDevice properties.

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava I just did, and there is nothing more than what UIdevice supports.

Answer (score 2):

All that `UIDevice` provides is the level as you pointed out, along with its [current state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevicebatterystate) (see below). The remaining items you are interested in would either require the use of private APIs which would get your app rejected from the store, or are simply not available to you via any API.

For anyone looking to see what you can get from [UIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice) related to battery, this covers the official Apple API:

- `var batteryLevel: CGFloat` returns a value from 0.0 (empty) to 1.0 (full)
- `var isBatteryMonitoringEnabled: Bool` returns `true` or `false` depending on whether or not you want to be notified of changes to the battery state. Setting it to true allows you to get the `batteryState`
- `var batteryState: UIDeviceBatteryState` provides the battery state, or `unknown` if `isBatteryMonitoringEnabled` is set to false.

The possible states are:

`unknown` - The battery state for the device cannot be determined.

`unplugged` - The device is not plugged into power; the battery is discharging.

`charging` - The device is plugged into power and the battery is less than 100% charged.

`full` - The device is plugged into power and the battery is 100% charged.

Comment: well, it's not surprising because I have searched a lot about this issue. I think i'll just give up it. Thanks!